# How to extend many types of classes, keeping some of their methods?

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented

I have a base abstract class that have many methods, and multiple subclasses that extends it and implementing the methods. I have another type of subclass that need to wrap the subclass and extend some of its methods.

Example:

```
abstract class AbstractClass {
   item: Item;
   constructor() {}
   abstract setItemType()
   abstract setItemName()
   setItemStuffThatNotVarySoNotAbstract() { ... }
   getItem() { return this.item }
   ...
}

class ConcreteClassA {
   item: Item;
   constructor() {}
   setItemType() {
     this.item.type = "typeA"
   }
   setItemName() {
     this.item.type = "typeB"
   }
}
```

now i want to have another wrapper class that will implement only specific methods

```
class ConcreteClassAExtention extends ConcreteClassA {
   setItemType() {
     this.item.type = "typeA"
   }
}
```

I can't do it for all of the classes because I will have a lot of classes which are all basically doing the same thing only extends a different class.

I thought about doing a decorator but I will need to implement all of the base class methods and also every time I'll add a method I'll need to add it to the decorator to implement the parent, and because my class is changing the item ill need to expose it so the decorator could change it.

I also thought to make the `setItemType` as abstract method to another class and then construct every thing in an abstract factory but I think it'll be too much overhead.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Right now you're only explaining how you want to build it but it is unclear whether your current approach is the right approach.

Comment: Decorator pattern?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a wrapper class for that.

You only have to segregrate the interface. Create an interface with only that method:

```java
interface TypeSettable {
    public void setItemType();
}
```

Then add it to the base class:

```java
abstract class AbstractClass implements TypeSettable {
    /* many abstract methods to implement including setItemType that is required by TypeSettable interface */
};
```

That way every subclass of AbstractClass will be implementing the `TypeSettable()` method (which they already do).

```java
public class A extends AbstractClass {
    public void setItemType() {
        
    }
    
    /* Implements many methods besides setItemType() */
}
```

When you cast an instance of a subclass of `AbstractClass` you can cast it to `TypeSettable` and you will only have the `setItemType()` method.

```java
// instantiate an A
AbstractClass a = new A();
// cast it to a TypeSettable when needed
TypeSettable t = (TypeSettable)a;
/* now you have t, that only has setItemType() */
```